# Signal a Task is ready but will never complete

Tags: .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I need to open some TCP ports and I want to signal when all ports are open, but these task will not complete since they're listening for an incoming tcp packet.

```
public partial class TcpServer
{
    protected override void Init()
    {
        var ports = Enumerable.Range(17001, 32);
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (int port in ports)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => new Listener(port)));
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());   //this will never complete
        Console.WriteLine("Server ready!"); //I want to signal this when every port is opened
    }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var task = Task.Run(() => new TcpServer().Init());
        Tasks.WaitAll(task);
    }
}

public class Listener
{
 public Listener(int port)
    {
        _puerto = port;
        Escuchar(port);
    }
    private void Escuchar(int port)
    {
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(GetLocalIPAddress()), port);
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine($"Listening at port {_puerto}");
        var error = false;
        while (!error)
        {
            try
            {
                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient(); //blocks here waiting for incoming packet
                var stream = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                var data = stream.ReadToEnd();
                Evento evento = Parsear(data);
                evento.Procesar();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                 listener.Stop();
                 error = true;
            }
        }
        Escuchar(port);
    }
}
```

I'd like to signal the console when all ports are open and ready to listen for incoming packets   Console.WriteLine("Server ready!");

Comment: What does `Listener` looks like?

Comment: edit made with `Listener`

Comment: How could this complete, if you start infinite loop in Task? And even if you got an error, you recusively start another loop. After time, you'll just get StackOverflowException.

Comment: That's because I purposely wrote those comments. I do want `Task.WaitAll` to never complete. I just want to know when the ports are "ready", but ready doesn't mean the Task is completed. Also, the recursive loop is in case something fails and I reopen the port. You suggest there's a better way to deal with TCP exceptions?

Comment: Do not do recursive call, start new task. You can use the CountdownEvent for signalling

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way might be to not do it all in one function. Move the opening of the port to the constructor for example:

```
    var ports = Enumerable.Range(17001, 32);

    var listeners = ports.AsParallel(port => new Listener(port)).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine("Server ready!"); 

    var listeningTasks = listeners.Select(listener => Task.Run(listener.Listen)).ToArray();

    // now this line will block
    Task.WaitAll(listeningTasks);
```

With slight changes to the listener:

```
public class Listener
{
    public Listener(int port)
    {
        _puerto = port;
        listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(GetLocalIPAddress()), port);
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine($"Listening at port {_puerto}");
    }

    public void Listen()
    {
        var error = false;
        while (!error)
        {
            try
            {
                TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient(); //blocks here waiting for incoming packet
                var stream = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                var data = stream.ReadToEnd();
                Evento evento = Parsear(data);
                evento.Procesar();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                 listener.Stop();
                 error = true;
            }
        }
        Listen();
    }
}
```